# html sidebar won't collapse between 767px and 785px,how do i fix it?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm using ADMINLTE to build a website 
and have a page that it sidebar won't collapse between 767 pixel and 785 pixel
other pages have no problem, so i inspect my page and compare
the working page shows the below classes

`class='skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse'`
and `class='skin-blue sidebar-mini'`

and the problem page is 
'skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-open' and
'skin-blue sidebar-mini'

and i check this is the part causes the issues
when the iterate more than 4

```
 for ($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++){

        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6">  
        <form method="post">  
        <div style="border:1px solid #3c8dbc; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:4px 4px; margin-top:10px; margin-right:-11px; margin-left:-11px;" align="center" onClick="document.forms[''].submit();" >  
        <img class="menu_m_img" src="dist/img/<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" /><br />  
        <h4 class="text-info" style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo mb_strimwidth($row["name"], 0, 18, "...");?></h4>
        <h4 class="text-danger">RM<?php echo $row["name_id"]; ?></h4>                   

        <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="border:none; color:#fff; border-radius:5px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat; width:100%" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary" />                                 
        </div>  
        </form>  
        </div>  
        <?php  
        }
        }else{?>
        <table class="table table-condensed" id="table" style ="margin-top:10px;">
        <td colspan="4" align="center">No results found</td>
        </table>                        
        <?php 
        }                                   
        ?>
```

why is this happens and how do i solve this ?
and may i know how it change the class when i press the button, how it add collapse or -open at class?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see how the error is originated and how to fix it. But please do not just copy your whole code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `sidebar-open` as body class, it means you pressed the button and want the sidebar to be open. I don't know how you got it there. You con programatically remove it with `$('body').removeClass('sidebar-open');`.

Answer (score 0):

tried at other machine, problem not recreated, it only occur in my devices, so for those have this problem try at others devices first ...